# Amazon Cloudfront CDN integration Into NUXT.js

Tags: nuxt.js, amazon-cloudfront

I have website developed into nuxtjs. I have created AWS Cloudfront CDN instance and configured it.

Cloudfront cdn url is working fine and showing exact copy of my nuxtjs domain website.

**My Requirement : I want nuxtjs project templates to serve all static content such as images, css and js  from cloudfront instead of my existing domain folder.** Can anyone guide me how to do that?

Steps I did :

- Build Nuxt.js website
- Created AWS S3 bucket and cloundfront instance. Also verified that cloud front url has exact copy of my domain.
- I added "build : publicPath" of my CDN domain url into my `nuxt.config.js` file.

I have used

```
build: {
   publicPath: 'https://AWS_CDN_ID.cloudfront.net' 
}
```

AWS_CDN_ID is my cloudfront.net instance id.

When I do `npm run build` It generates dist folder, But i could not found CDN url used anywhere for static content.

Can anyone please guide me what else i have to do here to use Amazon Cloudfront CDN url into static content during nuxt build ??

**How to use content from cloudfront into NUXT.js templates ??**

Thanks

ref.
https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-build

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> Then, when launching nuxt build, upload the content of .nuxt/dist/client directory to your CDN and voilà!

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/configuration-glossary/configuration-build#publicpath

When configuring Cloudfront you have chosen an origin of your data, from what I understand your intention is to use S3. So in your case you should run the `build` command and afterwards copy the contents of .nuxt/dist/client to your S3 bucket.

The public link to the CDN is shown when setting it up, not sure if the AWS_CDN_ID you're trying to use is valid. Public link to CDN is here:

[image]